# How to access Child Context in UWP Frame?

Tags: c#, uwp

Can you tell me How to access Child Context in UWP Frame??
(I'm using Frame Control. (MyFrame is Frame Control)

```
public sealed partial class MyPage: Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.ChildPage));
    }
}
```

so, how to access the context of 'Pages.ChildPage'??

for example,

```
Pages.ChildPage.iTestVariable = 1;
Pages.ChildPage.doTestFunction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the child page after navigation like this:

```
var childPage = MyFrame.Content as Pages.ChildPage;
if ( childPage != null )
{
   childPage.doTestFunction();
}
```

Of course, it is necessary to keep in mind that you can access only `public` methods and properties from outside the class itself.

Comment: I Appreciate it! you saved me. this is what i wanted to know.

Comment: Glad to help :-) . Happy coding!